# How to upload images from Android device to Facebook Server

Tags: android

Friend's ,
      I need to upload an image from android device to Facebook server of the login users profile,anyone help me to implement this feature by using corresponding API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk - Check the readme file to learn more about this SDK.